# Gson: deserialize MySQL datetime to Java Object

Tags: java, android, mysql, datetime, gson

Basically, `MySQL` `DATETIME` data type's format is this one: "2014-02-14 16:43:04" but when deserializing with `Gson` I get a `Unparseable date: "2014-02-14 16:43:04"`.

I'm guessing I'm using an incorrect object for this, I'm using `java.sql.Timestamp;` what is the correct object for this, or is it that I need to configure some date format to `Gson`? if so, how to?

**Edit:** What happens with the `setDateFormat()` if I use `DATE` (yyyy-mm-dd) and also `DATETIME`(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss), will any of them be affected?

Comment: Try using a Gson's `setDateFormat` like this: `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create()`

Comment: if I use DATE (yyyy-mm-dd) and also DATETIME(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss), will any of them be affected?

Answer (score 4):

Try using a Gson `setDateFormat` like this:

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create()`

Pretty sure you need a regular `Date` object as well.

Comment: if I use DATE (yyyy-mm-dd) and also DATETIME(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss), will any of them be affected?

Comment: If you've got multiple date formats then you'll have to get a little more creative. You can write a custom deserializer like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18337283/772385

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom dateformat for Gson by using the [`GsonBuilder`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) class. This has a method [`setDateFormat`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setDateFormat%28java.lang.String%29) where you can set your own format (which will be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" in your case).