# How to enforce DateTime format in Spring Boot API Request?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, datetime

I have a class like this. I want to enforce that the two Date fields should take in the request only if the date in request comes in a valid ISO Date time format like: `2021-01-19T12:20:35+00:00`

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Validated
public class EDDDetail {

  @NotBlank
  private String versionId;

  @NotNull
  private Date minTime;

  @NotNull
  private Date maxTime;
}
```

How to achieve this? Currently this accepts a date in long format (epoch time [e.g.: 1611058835000] ) and other valid dates as well like `22-02-2021` etc.
I want to throw a bad request if the date format in the request is not an ISO format date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @JsonFormat annotation with provided pattern to format the date

E.g:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@JsonFormat` annotation to define your pattern:

```
  @NotNull
  @JsonFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
  private Date minTime;

  @NotNull
  @JsonFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
  private Date maxTime;
```

If you want to accept multiple patterns you can get some implementation on this link: [Configure Jackson to parse multiple date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912992/configure-jackson-to-parse-multiple-date-formats)